# Best server setup for a website that streams videos/audio

Tags: web-hosting, audio, streaming, video-hosting

I have a entertainment website that host both videos and audio, these are the 2 problems I'm having:

1. Storage is a issue on my dedicated server, I'm going need more space soon
2. The site buckles when it gets a significant amount of traffic

I looked at numerous 3rd party videos/audio hosting solutions and they have very limited storage and are very expensive.

Storing files on Amazon is affordable at first but once you start to scale those charges skyrocket.

Should I host the website on one server and then use another to just stream the files? How would I even begin to setup something like that?

Looking for the most cost effective and most reliable solution.